# Lightweight Windows Mail Server / only for catch-all mail redirection

Tags: windows-server-2008, email-server

I have a small windows VPS running IIS7 and SQL Server. But I'd like to do mail as well.

The only functionality I'd like to add to it would be to:
Be able to make catch-all for my domains and make the received mail redirect to another email address.

So *@domain1.example would be sent to my Gmail. *@domain2.example would be sent to my colleague's Gmail, etc.

I just want it to be fast and lightweight. Free would be cool, too.

Comment: I stumbled upon hMailServer, it seems to fit my needs, any comments?

Answer (score 2):

If you want all mails redirected to Gmail, then you can accept it there instead. Without redirecting. All mails are handled at Google directly. This is called [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) and is free for no charge for a limited amount of users. And as I understood you only have one per domain.

Comment: OMG! I never thought of this! You are totally right! Thank you! I'll try it out right now! :-D

Answer (score 0):

MailEnable is a lightwieght and free Windows mail server, dead easy too

Google for it, you can set it up as easy or as complex as you like

Good luck